# libstdc++-6.dll error while running CPPUTest

Tags: gcc, cpputest

I'm trying to learn TDD using CPPUTest for embedded C unit testing. I was able to compile a basic C code using gcc on eclipse CDT. I was trying to compile the c++ files that come with CPPUTest. The machine I'm trying to run is 64-bit Windows 7 OS. I have installed i686-w64-mingw32 binary package from sourceforge for gcc.

The compilation of the test cpp files and linking using make all was successful. But when the tests started running I got the following error.

"The Program can't start because libstdc++-6.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem."

But, I find libstdc++6.dll under mingw/mingw/lib. I have added this to the path. Still it doesn't seem to run the tests.

Any suggestions to fix this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

hi go to this address and download TDM-GCC compiler and befor instal that clean last mingw 
http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/